# Simple sql query not working

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2005

I tried to insert some data into my database (sql server/local file) but it doesn't work.

```
public bool SaveCookie(string cookie, string expires)
{
    SimpleDBM db = new SimpleDBM();
    db.Connect();
    try
    {
        string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Cookies(cookie_value, cookie_expires) VALUES('{0}', '{1}');", cookie, expires);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        //... 
        SqlDataReader data = db.Query(ref cmd);
        return data.Read();
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Close();
    }
}
```

The `SimpleDBM` class:

```
public class SimpleDBM {

    public static string dbpath = @"...";
    public static string dbname = "db.mdf";
    public static string dfullPath = Path.Combine(dbpath, dbname);
    public static string connStr = string.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True", dfullPath);

    private SqlConnection con; 

    public void Connect()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connStr;
        con.Open();
    }

    public SqlDataReader Query(ref SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Can someone point out my mistake? For other queries it seems to work fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get? or are you not getting a error at all and it is just not inserting?

Comment: The exception should tell you what the error is.

Comment: Fee fi fo fum, I smell a SQL injection.

Comment: @TheMask: use **parametrized queries!** Don't string together your SQL statements, but use : `INSERT INTO Cookies(cookie_value, cookie_expires) VALUES(@Cookie, @Expires);` and then set the values for the parameters in your `SqlComamnd`. See Scott Chamberlain's answer - he shows it very nicely and in full detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you're trying to execute a query that doesn't return a result set using the [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) method of the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) class which will attempt to execute your query and create and return a DataReader for an eventual result set.

You should use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` sql statements.

---

**SIDE NOTE**

Not that it's the reason you're getting the error but you should also consider using SqlParamters instead of composing the values into the `INSERT` statement. Using prepared SQL statements generally gives a performance enhancement and also helps prevent SQL injection attacks.

For an example of using prepared statements, see the MSDN page or the [Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a ExecuteReader when you should be using ExecuteNonQuery.

Not related to your error you really should not be using `String.Format` with SqlCommand. What you should do is

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Cookies(cookie_value, cookie_expires) VALUES(@cookie, @expires);", cookie, expires);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cookie", cookie);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expires", expires);
cmd.CommandText = query;
```

With your method ask your self if someone passed a cookie of `' '');  Drop table Cookies --`? This is called a "Sql Injection Attack" and is one of the top 5 reasons websites get hacked.

**EDIT**

Just to help give another example of why using String.Format to pass values you did not generate is bad.
[image: http://xkcd.com/327/]

Comment: while the XKCD strip is funny, the blanket statement that "String.Format" is bad is a bit misleading. In fact String.Format is really useful - what's bad is using it to generated SQL statement because of the SQL Injection problem (and possibly others). Just a thought ;)